# How to split this string into two

Tags: java, regex

I have a string = `123456789\ABC 123\ABC123`

Using regex I have split this into two. The output should look like this

Group1 = `123456789`  Group2 = `123\ABC123`

Comment: Why use a regex at all, instead of just splitting on the first `/`?

Comment: I suggest you roll back your edit as it invalidates the context for both answers.If you have a different use case,you should ask a new question (or better,use the provided answers to figure the solution on your own in this instance).

Comment: @priya: In future, do not edit your question such that it invalidates existing answers. Instead, ask a new question. For more info, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298798/editing-questions-after-initial-post

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question displays minimal effort and the requisites have changed drastically after a few good answers were posted.

Answer (score 0):

Try not to completely alter your question rendering all answers useless. Having said that, this is one way you can tackle your (new) problem:

```
String str= "123456789\ABC 123\ABC123";

//"\\\\" is required to properly escape the backslash character
String[] split =  str.split("\\\\",2); //splits into 2 

String group1 = split[0];

//split[1] would now contain the String "ABC 123\ABC123". split it again by whitespace character to obtain `group2`
String[] temp = split[1].split("\\s+",2);
String group2 = temp[1];
```